Севкабель-порт через дефис надо?
Есть правило, что при родовом слове после собственного имени ставится дефис: Нева-река, Байкал-озеро. Правильно ли его распространить и на порты? Севкабель-порт (в СПб пространство так называется), Одесса-порт?

Правильно:
Севкабель Порт, общественное пространство "Севкабель Порт".
История названий:
(1) Завод "Сименс и Гальске" с 1875 года
(2) Северный кабельный завод, завод "Севкабель" с 1918 года
(3) Севкабель Порт с 2017 года
Почему в названии этой площадки есть слово «Порт»? Потому, что здесь когда-то из терминала катушки с кабелем грузились прямо на корабли.
Итак, Порт — это условное название площадки, а не реальный порт. Как и все условные названия,  слово входит в имя собственное и пишется с прописной буквы и без дефиса.
ИНФОРМАЦИЯ
Из статьи Что такое «Севкабель Порт» в Петербурге? Порт или портал в ...
Производственный комплекс «Севкабель» — это производитель 
кабельно-проводниковой продукции и первый кабельный завод в 
дореволюционной России. 2016 году руководство завода 
оптимизировало производство. Часть его территории 
освободилась. И на этом месте решено было создать культурно- 
деловое пространство с различными зонами для отдыха.
Почему в названии этой площадки есть слово «Порт»? Потому, 
что здесь когда-то из терминала катушки с кабелем грузились 
прямо на корабли.

Из история завода
В 1879 году была создана мануфактура в рамках торгового дома 
"Сименс и Гальске"(Siemens&Halske), занимающаяся 
производством ламп, кабелей и переключателей. Эта фирма 
первой соединила телеграфную сеть Петербурга с Москвой и 
начала изготавливать радиотелеграф в промышленных масштабах, 
изобретенный Александром Поповым.

В период первой мировой войны (1914-1918гг) в России 
произошло национализирование всех компаний, контролируемых 
немецким капиталом.

В "Северном кабельном заводе" (СКЗ) после Гражданской войны 
начался процесс модернизации: цеха были отремонтированы, 
закуплены новые станки, и компания расширила свой персонал.

С 1945 по 1975 год советский Северный кабельный завод 
пережил второе возрождение и производил новые инновационные 
технологии, не смотря на то, что производство было 
восстановлено до предвоенного уровня только к 1948 году.

Официально:  ООО "УК "Севкабель Порт"

Что-то вы меня игнорите, ну да ладно. Хороший ответ. Писать стали с большой буквы, так как название организации. Насчёт без кавычек название - это странно.

Игнорите?   Ну что вы,  вы меня всегда только восхищаете))  Или я что-нибудь пропустила?  // Спасибо за голос. // Если нет приложения, то пишут без кавычек,  например: https://dzen.ru/a/ZOtF5hbjggfgw11r   А вы случайно не были там?

Есть название общественного пространства  – это одно (имя собственное),  а название управляющей организации  – другое. Они арендовали у завода помещение, оформили его на свой вкус и дали ему название.

Я же вам отчёты слал) что я позвонил в словарь, и что потом туда письмо писал и мне таки ответили, а вы не ответили) оба раза). Насчёт кавычек понятно, но это интернет же, много чего пишут. Название писать надо в кавычках, без кавычек пишутся только латинизмы же... Насчёт дефисного написания - видимо это топонимы, а порт - это не топоним, а созданное человеком  место названное таким образом - порт, поэтому отдельно. По идее нужно "Севкабель порт" писать, потому что "Порт" - зачем?

Не могу найти, вы про  преподавателя писали. да? И что же вам ответили? //  В теме про названия мы с вами никак не пересекаемся, это я заметила)) Помните, команды кошачьи обсуждали и еще лекарства. Так и не договорились...

Ну про РЕЧЬ я писал, помните, в БРЭ)

В чате недавнем, где "сложный корень" который не корень, а формант, там чат, можно туда пойти. "Помните, команды кошачьи обсуждали и еще лекарства. " - команды с названиями кошачьими? Что-то помню, но не очень детали вылетают), про лекарство что-то было тоже, если напомните, то вспомню наверное. У меня память работает через логику во многом, а не через запоминание чисто деталей.

Опять игнорите?)

Еле нашла тему, поисковик помог)

ВАм ответ интересен, постить его в чат сюда?

Ответ интересен,  куда-нибудь надо поместить.  В ту тему, под ответом.

Давайте продолжим обсуждение в чате.
